# redirect rewrite logs to file in apache 2.4 windows installation

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, apache-2.4

While attempting to migrate my apache 2.2 webserver to apache 2.4 I an unable to transform this particular snippet.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLogLevel 0
RewriteLog "logs/rewrite_80.log"
```

What would the apache 2.4 compatible code for this be.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: yes, I have gone through that document and wasn't able to understand how the logs are getting redirected to a file. From what I understood, i am using tail on the error log and then grep for a string. but how to redirect it to a new file.

Comment: that tail part looks like it needs to be executed on a shell, how to make the configuration such that rewrite logs are sent into a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

I too am saddened by this discovery, but it looks like this capability (logging rewrites to a separate log file) was removed in Apache 2.4.

The suggestion in the documentation, referred to in the comments above, is to increase the log level specifically for mod_rewrite with something like this

```
# note that the example in the docs combines this with 'LogLevel alert'
# you can do them separately, too
LogLevel rewrite:trace3
```

…and then extract the specific log messages from the `ErrorLog` file for the server/vhost using a Unix shell command like

```
tail -f error_log | fgrep '[rewrite:'
```

The Windows rendition of that would probably involve [`FINDSTR`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) or some equivalent PowerShell commands. (Not my area of expertise, apologies.)

Note that the module won't log anything at all up to a level of `debug`, so the `rewrite:traceN` really is necessary if you want to troubleshoot your rewrites:

> [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) offers detailed logging of its actions at the `trace1` to `trace8` log levels. The log level can be set specifically for `mod_rewrite` using the [`LogLevel`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel) directive: Up to level `debug`, no actions are logged, while `trace8` means that practically all actions are logged.

references: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45379335) [2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging)